# Translation of form input

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.3

I'm currently internationalising my cake-php-webapp which is working very fine.
Everything is translated but form inputs:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class' => 'form-control'));
```

This generates a label

```
<label for="UserName">Name</label>
```

How can I specify that "Name" should be translated as well?

I think this would be the best way I know so far:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label'=>__('field_name')));
```

But is there a way without specifying the label?

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 2.3, if you take a look in the built-in FormHelper class:

```
 public function label($fieldName = null, $text = null, $options = array()) {

 ...  

 if ($text === null) {

        if (strpos($fieldName, '.') !== false) {
            $fieldElements = explode('.', $fieldName);
            $text = array_pop($fieldElements);
        } else {
            $text = $fieldName;
        }
        if (substr($text, -3) === '_id') {
            $text = substr($text, 0, -3);
        }

        $text = __(Inflector::humanize(Inflector::underscore($text)));
    }

 ...

}
```

It looks to me like if you don't set the label text, it derives your label text from the field name, then calls the translate function on it.

Have you tried just creating an input without specifying the label text, then saving a translation for the text that automatically gets generated for that input's label in your corresponding .po file?

Comment: Sure. The translation doesn't get generated for those labels which are automatically generated, like in my case name.